# Ruby bundler installs puma gem but puma cannot then find it's extensions

Tags: ruby, bundler, puma

I'm trying to install and run puma.

My gemfile has the local extracted gems (the server has no internet access and bundler is install via gem install):

```
gem 'rack', '=2.0.3', :path => "/opt/app-root/src/gems/rack-2.0.3"
gem 'puma', '=3.11.0', :path => "/opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0"
```

I run bundle like so:

```
bundle install --local --path ./bundle --deployment
```

Which produces:

```
Using bundler 1.16.1
Using puma 3.11.0 from source at `/opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0`
Using rack 2.0.3 from source at `/opt/app-root/src/gems/rack-2.0.3`
Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 3 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./bundle`
```

Then running:

```
bundle exec "puma --config puma.cfg"
```

Produces the problem with the missing ext:

```
/opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:15:in `require': cannot load such file -- puma/puma_http11 (LoadError)
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:1:in `require'
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:1:in `require'
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:4:in `require'
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:5:in `require'
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/bin/puma:6:in `require'
    from /opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/bin/puma:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/app-root/src/ruby/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/puma:22:in `load'
    from /opt/app-root/src/ruby/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/puma:22:in `<main>'
```

I can find very little information about this issue, except this post  https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/5398 which may or may not be a similar issue - but I don't know how to resolve it (re-running bundler install doesn't help me!)

By the way, the ext is present in the extracted gem as you'd expect:

> opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.11.0/ext/puma_http11

Answer (score 0):

The `puma11` stuff in `ext` is a compiled library; the result of that compilation as `puma_http11.bundle` then gets copied to the `lib/puma` directory, as part of the installation process.  Do you have this .bundle file?

I'm guessing you have a problem or missing steps in your local extraction process to build or copy the native code portions of Gems (including this one) - the Rakefile in the puma repository on Github includes steps to build the native pieces using ragel.